# Python WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))

Tags: python

I'm trying to do `pip install --upgrade pip` and keep
getting this error:

```py
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnection
Error('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000026F50B448C8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made
 because the target machine actively refused it'))': /simple/pytest/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnection
Error('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000026F50B59148>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made
 because the target machine actively refused it'))': /simple/pytest/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnection
Error('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000026F50B596C8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made
 because the target machine actively refused it'))': /simple/pytest/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnection
Error('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000026F50B595C8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made
 because the target machine actively refused it'))': /simple/pytest/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnection
Error('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000026F50B5F2C8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made
 because the target machine actively refused it'))': /simple/pytest/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pytest
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pytest
```

Also, I can't install any new package due to this error.
I tried to reinstall Pycharm but no luck there.
I tried some other suggested solutions online - still no luck.
I understand it has something to do with Proxy but I am not familiar with it, Anyone?

Comment: The error message spells this out pretty clearly; your proxy is down, or your proxy configuration is broken. We don't have access to either, so really cannot troubleshoot this for you.

Comment: @tripleee what can you suggest I should do? How can I "reactive" my proxy which according to you is down?

Comment: Show us how it's configured first. If it's a corporate or ISP's proxy you may have to contact your local IT support.

Comment: Not a fleshed out answer, so leaving it as a comment: I got a bunch of `NewConnectionError`s trying to pip install inside of a VSCode .devcontainer. It turned out that I ran out of space allocated for my images and networking got disabled on the container. Not very intuitive, but it started working after I deleted some extraneous images.

Answer (score 11):

Try appending your build command with ***--network=host***
Eg : `docker  build -t cointainer_name .  --network=host`

```
If you use the host network mode for a container, that container’s network stack is not isolated from the 
Docker host (the container shares the host’s networking namespace), and the container does not 
get its own IP-address allocated. 
For instance, if you run a container which binds to port 80 and you use host 
networking, the container’s application is available on port 80 on the host’s IP address.
```

Check [here](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/) for more details

Answer (score 5):

## TL;DR for Windows, this works for me.

1. `Windows` + `I` (to open Settings).
2. Choose `Network & Internet`
3. Choose `Proxy`
4. Check `Manual proxy setup` to be in the `Off`-position

---all starts to work here already---

5. Note: `Automatically detect settings` switched to `On` or to `Off` cause no influence for me (all still continue to work as it started to work after 4.).

## Pre-story

> I had the same error. Can't install libs by `pip`, by `pipenv`, by anaconda, by PyCharm. Then I checked `Proxy` setting (Windows 11 OS) and noticed I have some `Manual proxy setup` defined. When disable it - the problem was fixed.

> The problem began very spontaneously: I did some python-work, did some installations (maybe some pithon-module with `pipenv` like notebook or jupyter-lab, `cygwin` tool etc.) and then installing/updating of the python-modules was crashed. Maybe some installations changed the proxy-parameters? I don't know.
> Python re-installing didn't help.

## Errors examples

For example, anaconda error while installing/updating looks like:

```
CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

'https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64'
```

Pip error while installing/updating looks like:

```bash
pip install --upgrade pip
```

```
>>>
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))': /simple/pip/
```

Answer (score 2):

First, reinstalling all python.
Secondly, once python is installed I went to find the host file and uncomment the section of the host.
Normally, the path in windows is located in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

Uncomment this section:

## localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost
```

Hope it serves!
cheers!

Answer (score 2):

## My Env

- python3.8
- windows10 + WSL
- pip 21.0.4

## What's my step

1. `conda create -n py38 python=3.8`
2. `pip install pandas`

And then I got that error "Warning, retry ..."

## How I solve the problem

**Just reboot my machine.**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
winget install -id Microsoft.Powershell --source winget
winget install -id Microsoft.Powershell.Preview --source winget
```

Enter the above commands in the PowerShell, then after that close the Pycharm environment, then start it again. It worked for me to install pip.

Answer (score 0):

my .bash_profile had:

```
export SSLKEYLOGFILE=/Users/X/sslkeylog.log
```

removing the **SSLKEYLOGFILE** definition fixed the issue. seems like Python 3.8+ added support for SSL key logging, and it somehow causes issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a corporate network or within VPN, you might have access to reach these packages, Disconnect from those networks and connect with normal networks or even Hotspot of your phone should solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all go to `settings => network&proxy => proxy` and set manual proxy setup to off. then make sure your internet connection is okay and you are not connected to any VPN.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking your firewall. in my case Kaspersky blocked pip

Comment: this looks like a comment and not the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Separate your credentials from your extra-index-url list

Wrong way:

- /etc/pip.conf:

```
    ; Low timeout
    timeout = 20
    
    ; Custom index
    extra-index-url =
       https://username:password@artylab.myco.com/artifact_root/artifact_path/pypi/
        https://username:password@artylab.myco.com/artifact_root/artifact_path2/pypi/
```

Right way:

- /etc/pip.conf

```
    ; Low timeout
    timeout = 20
    
    ; Custom index
    extra-index-url =
       https://artylab.myco.com/artifact_root/artifact_path/pypi/
       https://artylab.myco.com/artifact_root/artifact_path2/pypi/
```

- ~/.netrc

```
login username
password password
```

Answer (score -1):

If after install pip you have errors like this on windows with python 3.10

> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None,
> redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
> 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', PermissionError(13, 'Permission
> denied'))': /simple/pip/

**try updating windows(OS) environment variables**. close your **windows** user session and re-enter. It work for me.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you are not connected to a VPN connection