# How to fix Connection Error during Anaconda Package Installation

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I am using a VDI (Virtual Desktop Infrastructure) provided by my client. When I try to install packages using pip in the Anaconda Prompt `pip install tensorflow`, I am getting this error message below:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/tensorflow/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/tensorflow/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/tensorflow/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/tensorflow/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/tensorflow/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

I found one answers for this error message here on stackoverflow but unfortunately that isn't working. I had a feeling that this might be due to a firewall so I turned off all firewall but no luck.
Please share a solution in case anyone has come across something similar.

Comment: Please try again by rebooting the system and let us know if the issue still persists. Here I have attached a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67547176/python-warning-retrying-retrytotal-4-connect-none-read-none-redirect-none) for your reference.

Comment: Yeah I tried this suggested issue prior to posting it here but no luck. Good thing is it turns out that the support team from the client side had an SOP in place for this issue and it is working now.

Comment: Good to know that your issue has resolved. Thanks for confirming.