# Unable to install pyinstaller in anaconda environment

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda, pyinstaller

I have an environment in Anaconda called `myEnv`. I am trying to install pyinstaller to it. I tried all 3 of the options given here https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pyinstaller for installing pyinstaller, however, none of them worked.

This is what the message looks like in Anaconda Prompt:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve. 

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
-pyinstaller
```

This is weird since I do have `conda-forge` as a channel:

```
conda config --show channels
```

The response is:

```
channels:
- defaults
- conda-forge
```

As a last resort, I tried `pip install pyinstaller` and that gave an error.

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required'))': /simple/pyinstaller/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyinstaller (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyinstaller
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.
```

**Edit:** I also tried `conda update conda` but that still didn't seem to do the trick.

Installing it from the Anaconda channel also didn't work:

```
conda install -c anaconda pyinstaller
```

It just gave me the same error when I tried to install `pyinstaller` from the `conda-forge` channel.

Some Extra Details:

My Python version: 3.10.9

Laptop: Windows 64

Comment: Looks like a duplicate, no? See [ProxyError when installing a package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67547176/python-warning-retrying-retrytotal-4-connect-none-read-none-redirect-none). Can you install anything else, by the way?

Comment: @Vitalizzare I already checked out this post. I don't have permission to install docker. Also, my organization doesn't allow me to alter the proxy settings.

Comment: What about [configuring pip with proxy authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43473041/how-to-configure-pip-per-config-file-to-use-a-proxy-with-authentification)? Sort of `pip install pyinstaller --proxy https://user_name:password@proxyname:port`

Comment: why you don't use Python virtualenv `python -m venv venv`?

Comment: You may have a dependency conflict with another package. Try starting with a clean environment and add your other packages after pyinstall. `conda env export --from-history` is helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly install [`pyinstaller`](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/installation.html#how-to-install-pyinstaller) from GitHub

```
python -m pip install git+https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller
```

If you're using a conda env file, you can also configure the package to be installed in the same way.

```
name: myEnv
channels:
dependencies:
   - pip:
     - "--editable=git+https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller"
     # other dependencies
```

Answer (score 2):

First I created a conda environment using the following command:

```
conda create --name myEnv
```

Now check the conda version with `conda --version`:

```
conda --version

conda 23.5.2
```

After that you could simply install the package using `conda install pyinstaller`:

```
conda install pyinstaller

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done


==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 23.5.2
  latest version: 23.7.2

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda

Or to minimize the number of packages updated during conda update use

     conda install conda=23.7.2



## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /Users/quinten/opt/miniconda3/envs/myEnv

  added / updated specs:
    - pyinstaller


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    altgraph-0.17.3            |  py311hecd8cb5_0          41 KB
    macholib-1.16.2            |  py311hecd8cb5_0          89 KB
    pip-23.2.1                 |  py311hecd8cb5_0         3.3 MB
    pyinstaller-5.6.2          |  py311h6c40b1e_0         1.2 MB
    pyinstaller-hooks-contrib-2022.14|  py311hecd8cb5_0         178 KB
    setuptools-68.0.0          |  py311hecd8cb5_0         1.2 MB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:         6.0 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  altgraph           pkgs/main/osx-64::altgraph-0.17.3-py311hecd8cb5_0 
  bzip2              pkgs/main/osx-64::bzip2-1.0.8-h1de35cc_0 
  ca-certificates    pkgs/main/osx-64::ca-certificates-2023.05.30-hecd8cb5_0 
  libffi             pkgs/main/osx-64::libffi-3.4.4-hecd8cb5_0 
  macholib           pkgs/main/osx-64::macholib-1.16.2-py311hecd8cb5_0 
  ncurses            pkgs/main/osx-64::ncurses-6.4-hcec6c5f_0 
  openssl            pkgs/main/osx-64::openssl-3.0.10-hca72f7f_0 
  pip                pkgs/main/osx-64::pip-23.2.1-py311hecd8cb5_0 
  pyinstaller        pkgs/main/osx-64::pyinstaller-5.6.2-py311h6c40b1e_0 
  pyinstaller-hooks~ pkgs/main/osx-64::pyinstaller-hooks-contrib-2022.14-py311hecd8cb5_0 
  python             pkgs/main/osx-64::python-3.11.4-hf27a42d_0 
  readline           pkgs/main/osx-64::readline-8.2-hca72f7f_0 
  setuptools         pkgs/main/osx-64::setuptools-68.0.0-py311hecd8cb5_0 
  sqlite             pkgs/main/osx-64::sqlite-3.41.2-h6c40b1e_0 
  tk                 pkgs/main/osx-64::tk-8.6.12-h5d9f67b_0 
  tzdata             pkgs/main/noarch::tzdata-2023c-h04d1e81_0 
  wheel              pkgs/main/osx-64::wheel-0.38.4-py311hecd8cb5_0 
  xz                 pkgs/main/osx-64::xz-5.4.2-h6c40b1e_0 
  zlib               pkgs/main/osx-64::zlib-1.2.13-h4dc903c_0 


Proceed ([y]/n)? y


Downloading and Extracting Packages
                                                                                
Preparing transaction: done                                                     
Verifying transaction: done                                                     
Executing transaction: done
```

Now let's check if the package is installed using `conda list pyinstaller`:

```
conda list pyinstaller

# packages in environment at /Users/quinten/opt/miniconda3/envs/myEnv:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
pyinstaller               5.6.2           py311h6c40b1e_0  
pyinstaller-hooks-contrib 2022.14         py311hecd8cb5_0
```

Answer (score 1):

Might not be pretty but you can download the .conda/.tar.bz2 file from the anaconda website, you can then install it with:

```
    conda install *filepath to file* --offline
```

Make sure you check for dependencies and ensure they are fulfilled prior.

Comment: After downloading the .conda file, does it need to be placed in any specific directory/folder in the Anaconda environment before running the command you posted?

Comment: No, just somewhere you can navigate to with the anaconda command prompt.  It would be easiest to place it on your C drive

Answer (score -1):

```
$ conda update conda
$ conda create -n new-env-name python=3.8  # Replace python=3.8 with your desired Python version
$ conda activate new-env-name
$ conda install -c conda-forge pyinstaller
$ pip install pyinstaller
```

If the env is already activated then only use install command to install `pyinstaller`.

Comment: `$ conda install` followed by `$ pip  install` makes no sense. What is the purpose?